# how to find cluster center in every iteration of k-means sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

How to get cluster centers for each iteration of `KMeans` in *scikit-learn* using Python.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++', max_iter=4, random_state=42)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)

print(kmeans.n_iter_)
centroid.append(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Comment: I'm affraid that won't be possible, centers are saved enclosed in the `fit()`'s scope [only the center for the best iteration is returned by that function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2e/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L1029).

Comment: Might it be possible to use `init` and `max_iter = 1` and then loop to convergence while recording `cluster_centers_` for each iteration?

Comment: how about the stop condition when the cluster has not changed anymore?